# Adding value based on date criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, count

Please see code below. For every that `Holiday` exists that is in between `UW_Date` and `UW_Date_Month_Start`, then I'd like to create a new column called `new_int` that is `UW_int` + the number of holidays that have occurred so far that month.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table6]
LEFT JOIN [] ON Table6.Name = ??
```

**Original Table:**

```
Name    | UW_Date    | UW_Date_Month_Start | UW_int |
-----------------------------------------------------
Kim     | 9/4/2019   | 9/1/2019            | 3      |
Billy   | 9/10/2019  | 9/1/2019            | 7      |
Steve   | 10/21/2019 | 10/1/2019           | 5      |
Nicki   | 10/10/2019 | 10/1/2019           | 1      |


Holiday  |
-------- |
9/4/2019 |
9/1/2019 |
```

```
CREATE TABLE [Table6] ([Name] nvarchar(10), [UW_Date] datetime, [UW_Date_Month_Start] datetime, [UW_int] int)

INSERT INTO [Table6] VALUES ('Kim', '9/4/2019', '9/1/2019', 3)
INSERT INTO [Table6] VALUES ('Billy', '9/10/2019', '9/1/2019', 7)
INSERT INTO [Table6] VALUES ('Steve', '10/21/2019', '10/1/2019', 5)
INSERT INTO [Table6] VALUES ('Nicki', '10/10/2019', '10/1/2019', 1)

CREATE TABLE [Holiday_Table] ([Holiday] datetime)

INSERT INTO [Holiday_Table] VALUES ('9/7/2019')
INSERT INTO [Holiday_Table] VALUES ('10/15/2019')
```

**Final Output:**

```
Name    | UW_Date    | UW_Date_Month_Start | UW_int | new_int
--------------------------------------------------------------
Kim     | 9/4/2019   | 9/1/2019            | 3      | 3
Billy   | 9/10/2019  | 9/1/2019            | 7      | 8
Steve   | 10/21/2019 | 10/1/2019           | 5      | 6
Nicki   | 10/10/2019 | 10/1/2019           | 1      | 1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems like a you just need a `(LEFT) JOIN` on `UW_Date` having a value larger than (or equal) to `holiday` and then aggregate with a `COUNT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this with an inline subquery. This avoids the need for aggregation, which can be expensive on an large number of records.

Also, when no holiday records exists for the corresponding interval, the subquery returns `0`, so there is no need handle `null` (unless when doing `left join`).

```
select
    t.*,
    t.UW_int + (
        select count(*) 
        from holiday_table h 
        where h.holiday between t.UW_Date_Month_Start and t.UW_Date
    ) new_int
from table6 t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee5de50d1b41568ea43e74da4f50a6cb)**:

```
Name  | UW_Date             | UW_Date_Month_Start | UW_int | new_int
:---- | :------------------ | :------------------ | -----: | ------:
Kim   | 04/09/2019 00:00:00 | 01/09/2019 00:00:00 |      3 |       3
Billy | 10/09/2019 00:00:00 | 01/09/2019 00:00:00 |      7 |       8
Steve | 21/10/2019 00:00:00 | 01/10/2019 00:00:00 |      5 |       6
Nicki | 10/10/2019 00:00:00 | 01/10/2019 00:00:00 |      1 |       1
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you!